# Adding the enemies

Tags: actionscript, actionscript-3

OK, so I have a laser gun and it is shooting lasers (well duh) called laser_mc and I am putting in the enemies now. There is one problem though. When I add the enemies named `bad` they get added, removed and then reappear somewhere else.

Here is my code. What did I do wrong?

```
var badadd:bad; badadd = new bad()

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, createbad);
function createbad(event:Event):void {
    addChild(badadd);
    badadd.x = Math.random()*stage.width;
    badadd.y= Math.random()*stage.height;
}

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, removebad);
function removebad(event:Event):void {
    if (laser_mc.hitTestObject(badadd)) {
        removeChild(badadd);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

They get removed and placed elsewhere because you are using an enter_frame loop here. Every single time a frame ticks off your program adds the *same* enemy at a random location. So it adds at a random place, removes it, then adds it at a random place all over again.

You might want to try something like this:

Set up a for loop and fill an array with enemies. Declare the array as a class property\, EnemyArray.    Like (pseudocode):

```
for i = 1 to 10
    var tempEnemy = new Enemy()
    EnemyArray[i].push(tempEnemy) // put the enemy in the array
```

Now when you need to add an enemy - it's already been instantiate so you just need to go:

```
addChild(tempEnemy[index]);
```

Now you can cycle through the array for hit testing, etc.

Let me know if this is too conceptual and I'll write the code out a bit more.

Comment: yeah i dont really understand all of this i get what the problem is but not how to fix it. Oh yeah i am not using classes thought i might let you know